# Is every simplicial $d$-sphere linearly embeddable in $\Bbb R^{d+1}$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, simplicial-complexes, embeddings

A *simplicial $d$-sphere* is a simplicial complex homeomorphic to the $d$-sphere. It is known that not every such complex can be embedded into $\Bbb R^{d+1}$ as the boundary complex of a convex simplicial polytope.
But what if we drop convexity (but keep that the embedded simplices must be flat)?

The paper [Nonconvex Embeddings of the Exceptional Simplicial 3-Spheres with 8 Vertices](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272565/1-s2.0-S0097316500X00313/1-s2.0-S0097316501932285/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHEZ6GJWaFeHGe85R1pWmYvW1HjbH6rkYZwsPDBosrmzAiBz82QggYlf3UUE%2FBukZhz2EkUQnfMEkH2SMYMDgXcigSrbBAiT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMiQWbSgYY6EP2gCwLKq8EXGKruyZU%2FeCUKWO%2FQqC6td4bp1syDEOGCV%2FEuSG4uc3Pt7ahQX5FV4%2B4hXoS77hsIuP5yvvwxYzMiZWa7NL0GVCNJBe6rLG9zBQNblGFqXOSEAe47QAvSLIA7k3DVSo407D7yZoZzb4t5y6YEggEimL0Fr9ceggrdpDbKsYKw3VJsKf72wRb3F%2FoxGZmvZpOt0yi24Poy8z1ccdZ7OayX44uWcxfZgrI9WCd5MDcNs0t98TF63nRwo%2FnIP5KMgJ18XKVmPV5fV%2B5%2Fo3CXH2YE2g4Mab5LJugsYGQGTCm11%2BraUC9XX%2Bu2RYnBz7ZC07PBGKkRW3icygTubKCj%2BwmkHywYursJ7wQT8JU4TUffTXOBxCfXwDuK8cCQ6zYgNS5lFzhJpOcMYLBWdWX8opH%2FHSY6plnaMNFWxBYUBg6ecQBHcEZpxThYpkftT%2F3LqbpobvsmB3XGfRwYbaecoCGZdWg%2B4gslskB9bUbuOs7Buyled0MXRFKBi3RxFuItB1EYNtYlGrOrxJGDlVZpFCEJufZdEUkhBdPhdaErhaLKF5GTbfmB2KUSPGgu0yC5bh4bE9emdy5uvVAsbR7Elxn%2B8zKazA5x%2F1hv87%2BPgbIHr0oFMkZ8LH6z7AOdS0oRYUw%2Bbd9BAt6qLk%2F6px2tTnI107Ia1wFw871B37LvyQ49PKfUigRH9G9s1F%2FbMOTE8UeLSs5ceGIsrImJLXadv3gGn0gOKRo2LLVEc5DHVB7VjCt57mUBjqqARYAU9ovd3G3UJEAdubJZXql8NSTgPpe%2FVZucqDVkardjqrH5ARNOqTQJpn%2F2cB3P8m4W79xBsMgiGgBpN0%2FN%2BPYjf%2BsFi7LypruxuUB5r5im7395eg%2BmKVdVQmAAitU%2F8PxXVzpPUBEtqwJOijzMtnySOJBI%2FPv6iJ6wvyNuIz2FlblZDfSUmIlzOKwx4AkzmWBNiBpXbPOQqO3t0weVQfu5Ad1%2ButdR6WY&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220525T185808Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYV4U5MGBB%2F20220525%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a05e3cdfcb17d7fcf8446d193e21b88280416cd57df1959eb5f09e83faf45fff&hash=7e8bc2789e423e5e1ef32c96d48cbd2f70c9885caa7dd48aee5dc5a6199c07b6&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0097316501932285&tid=spdf-fc287b06-7347-4004-b72a-186c1a43c349&sid=5e2d7c428f66574aa498f1a8c0024f38b806gxrqb&type=client&ua=4d545456565152575f04&rr=711080300f7e76d7) by Mihalisin and Williams states this as a conjecture:

> **Conjecture 5.2.** Every simplicial $d$-sphere is linearly embeddable
> in $\Bbb R^{d+1}$.

*Has there been any progress on this question* since 2002 when this paper appeared? For example, has this been verified for simplicial 3-spheres on 9 vertices?